# Datatabel + Server side processing = can not search in more than one column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using Datatabel + PHP Server side processing 
with SSP.class.php

the issue that I found that if I have i.e :

firstname , lastname , phone , email , date

and I want to search on firstname + lastname then I will not get any result

I get result only if I search for only firstname or last name or email so one field at time.

incase you want to take a look here is the ssp.class.php file

https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

Any idea how to make it search in firstname+lastname ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can not search like that. You should have one column of `fullname`, if you wan to search `firstname + lastname` together .

Comment: Or you can use the individual column searching.

Comment: I did not understand your first comment

Comment: Same as Werner's answer.

Comment: This solution did not worked, I still can not search this way

Comment: I think search process is working with your database not data served in datatable. In this case you can have individual column searching or you can add `fullname` column in your database.

Comment: I see what you mean, I was looking for better solution especially if I need to add additional options in future, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Why not generate a new column eg. 'fullname', being columns 'firstname' and 'lastname' concatenated. Eg. in MySQL

```
CONCAT(`firstname`, ` `, `lastname`)  AS `fullname`
```

and show this new column in your datatable???

Comment: This is a really nice idea!  but I will wait to see if there are any other solutions 

Thanks a lot

Comment: This solution did not worked, I still can not search this way